# UITableView is jumpy/choppy/jerky when scrolling up

Tags: ios, uitableview

I encountered this problem when using UITableView, the tableView's cells have different heights, and the auto layout constraints are set properly. When you scroll down to the bottom of tableView and load more data (no matter by using reloadData or insertRowsAtIndexPaths), and then scroll up, the tableView will start to be jumpy at some point, and then be jumpy all the time until you scroll to the very top.

Not only for my own project, I find this project on github ([link](https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8/issues/17)) have the same problem so that you can reproduce it.

Comment: can you give us  link of that github project to check out what you are saying ? .

Comment: @saketkumar Thanks for your inform, the link is added

Comment: Hello, do you have solution on this issue so far? I have the exact same problem with iOS 8 autolayout.

Comment: @KenHui, I calculate each cell's height "manually" to solve the problem (by implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath method)

Comment: Thanks @waterlee23 . I search through the Internet. Most people said the ios8 autolayout + auto height calculation is only for every cell has same dynamic height. No good for variance height.

Comment: @waterlee23 That's so frustrating. I took care to set up the autolayout and the result was a jumpy tableview and me having to do height calculations manually.

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve the problem? I finally solved this issue, the key is to calculate an estimated height. Seems like the more accurate estimate you return, the less jumpiness/choppiness.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 switch (yourTypeOfCell) {
     case something:
        return estimatedHeight;
        break;
     case default:
        return defaultValue;
        break;
 }
}
```