# UITableView jumpy scrolling for variable cell height

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have read many guides / suggestions online including this one [UITableView is jumpy/choppy/jerky when scrolling up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980740/uitableview-is-jumpy-choppy-jerky-when-scrolling-up)

I have variable cell heights:

```
self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

When I scroll up from the bottom, the scrolling is jumpy.

I tried implementing rowHeightForIndexPath and it causes performance problem as documented.

I saw the builtin iMessages app on iOS, and it is able to handle scrolling very smoothly despite variable cell height.

Any idea how?